# Warning on Text Widget in my main.dart file

Tags: flutter, warnings

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

void main() {
runApp(
const MaterialApp(

```
  home: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
    appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('I am Rich'),
    ),
  ),
)
```

);
}

I'm starting to study a new course on Flutter and get a warning saying "The constructor being called is not a constructor" Can somebody tell me why is that? It only appears when I add the Text Widget... What's wrong here? thank you in advance. I'm a total beginner

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('I am Rich'),
        ),
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

you should remove the `const` keyword in front of the `MaterialApp`, because `AppBar()` is not a const constructor

Comment: thank you, I just realized it after posting the question. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

```
home: Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('I am Rich'),
    ),
  ),
```

You should add const keyword before your Text Widget. Because you have added static text in Text Widget.

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
void main() { 
   runApp( 
    MaterialApp(
       home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent,
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('I am Rich'),
        ),
      ),
    )
    
    ); 
}
```

In your code const is creating problem here i have solve the error

If you dont use const it will work fine but it will show warning if you dont want any warning then use const before text widget